# What data structure to use for string templating?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, replace

In my application I have a set of parameters, and a set of string templates, characterized by having 0..N parameters (identified by curly braces) in them.

For example, here is a set of parameters:

```
1  {o}
2  {o-country}
3  {d}
4  {d-country}
```

Here is a sample template set (using all the parameters is not mandatory):

```
1  "flights from {o} to {d}"
2  "flights to {d-country}"
3  "flights from {o} to {d-country}"
```

The applications lets users define a number of concrete values combinations for the parameters and then apply them to the template set. When providing concrete values combinations for parameters, users have to provide a value for each existing parameter.

For example, here is a set of concrete values combinations:

```
1  <{o}="Milan",{o-country}="Italy",{d}="Madrid",{d-country}="Spain">
2  <{o}="Rome",{o-country}="Italy",{d}="London",{d-country}="UK">
3  <{o}="Milan",{o-country}="Italy",{d}="Paris",{d-country}="France">
4  <{o}="Rome",{o-country}="Italy",{d}="Dublin",{d-country}="Ireland">
```

When the concrete values are applied to the template set, the result would be this:

```
"flights from Milan to Madrid"
"flights to Spain"
"flights from Milan to Spain"

"flights from Rome to London"
"flights to UK"
"flights from Rome to UK"

"flights from Milan to Paris"
"flights to France"
"flights from Milan to France"

"flights from Rome to Dublin"
"flights to Ireland"
"flights from Rome to Ireland"
```

Assume that I have about 15 parameters, 1,000 concrete values combinations, and 50,000 templates: the end result would be 5,000,000 strings.

What is the best way to represent the string templates, the concrete value combinations in order to generate the result in the fastest way?

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you expect to be the main limiting factor? Have you made any measurements? I'd expect at that scale I/O will take up most of the time (assuming that you want to output the strings onto disk or across a network connection or display it on a screen).

Comment: My concern is time. Assume that I am not concerned about I/O or transfer over network, or that they could be the limiting factor. Also assume I keep everything in memory to simplify. What I want to avoid is a "naive" approach using a for-loop over the concrete values combinations and for each <parameter,value> pair call a substitute function on the single template string, since it seems overly inefficient time-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, with the extra clarification, here's what I'd do.

First I'd parse each template into an array of literals and an array of placeholder strings, like this:

```
"flights from {o} to {d}" ->
    String [] literals = { "flights from ", " to " };
    String [] placeholders = { null, "o", "d" };
```

`literals` represents the literal parts of the template, and `placeholders` tells us which key should be inserted before the i<sup>th</sup> element of `literals`. (`placeholders` contains one more element than `literals` so that we can handle cases where a template starts or ends with a placeholder.) This step is done once at the initialisation stage and only the parsed template is stored.

Then each value combination should be parsed into a map:

```
{"o":"Milan","o-country": "Italy","d":"Madrid", "d-country":"Spain" }
```

Once we have everything in a pre-parsed format, we can start generating strings from it:

```
public String combine( String [] literals, String [] placeholders, Map<String,String> values ) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < placeholders.length; i++) {
     if (placeholders[i] != null) { //a null value in the placeholders means nothing to substitute in that position
        sb.append( values.get( placeholders[i] ) );
     }
     if (i < literals.length) { //the literals array will always be 1 shorter than the placeholder
        sb.append( literals[i] );
     }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Or, if you don't want to go to the hassle of implementing a bespoke solution, you can just use [`java.text.MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html), which I think is usually implemented similarly, except it's far more complicated internally because it can handle much more complex patterns. :)

In fact I'd probably start with `MessageFormat` myself, I just wanted to show how it's done on a basic level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write you own <s>bicycle</s> template engine, then what you need is to store list of both predefined strings and param names that will be dynamically replaced with actual param values. When rendering template you need to iterate this list, resolving params to their values, and putting each piece to `StringBuilder`.

Take a look at the code:

```
    public class TemplateTest {
        /**
         * Template class. Provides method render
         * that takes actual params and renders the template
         */
        static class Template {
            private List<TemplatePiece> pieces;

            public Template(TemplatePiece... pieces) {
                //defencive copy
                this.pieces = new ArrayList<TemplatePiece>(Arrays.asList(pieces));
            }

            public String render(Map<String, String> params) {
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                for (TemplatePiece piece : pieces) {
                    result.append(piece.render(params));
                }
                return result.toString();
            }
        }

        interface TemplatePiece {
            String render(Map<String, String> params);
        }

        static class StringTemplatePiece implements TemplatePiece {
            private String string;

            StringTemplatePiece(String string) {
                this.string = string;
            }

            @Override
            public String render(Map<String, String> params) {
                return string;
            }
        }

        static class ParamTemplatePiece implements TemplatePiece {
            private String paramName;

            ParamTemplatePiece(String paramName) {
                this.paramName = paramName;
            }

            @Override
            public String render(Map<String, String> params) {
                String value = params.get(paramName);
                return value == null ? "{MISSING PARAM " + paramName + "}" : value;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Create StringTemplatePiece
         * Just a shortcuts for more fancy template test creation
         */
        private static StringTemplatePiece s(String name) {
            return new StringTemplatePiece(name);
        }

        /**
         * Create ParamTemplatePiece
         * Just a shortcuts for more fancy template test creation
         */
        private static ParamTemplatePiece p(String paramName) {
            return new ParamTemplatePiece(paramName);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Template template1 = new Template(s("flights from "), p("o"), s(" to "), p("d"));
            Template template2 = new Template(s("flights to "), p("d-country"));
            Template template3 = new Template(s("flights from "), p("o"), s(" to "), p("d-country"));

            HashMap<String, String> params1 = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("o", "Milan");
                put("d", "Madrid");
                put("o-country", "Italy");
                put("d-country", "Spain");
            }};
            System.out.println(template1.render(params1));
            System.out.println(template2.render(params1));
            System.out.println(template3.render(params1));
            System.out.println();

            HashMap<String, String> params2 = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("o", "Rome");
                put("d", "London");
                put("o-country", "UK");
                put("d-country", "Spain");
            }};
            System.out.println(template1.render(params2));
            System.out.println(template2.render(params2));
            System.out.println(template3.render(params2));
        }
    }
```

Result of execution is:

```
 flights from Milan to Madrid
 flights to Spain
 flights from Milan to Spain

 flights from Rome to London
 flights to Spain
 flights from Rome to Spain
```

Also consider using existent template engines, such as [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both biziclop, Aivean for their answers, they have confirmed my approach.

For what is worth, here is the implementation I did in JavaScript for a sample use case (note that each template line actually contains two separate strings);

```
var parameters = ['{d-airport-code}','{d-country}','{d}','{d-country-code}'];
var values = [
  ['ADD','Ethiopia','Addis Ababa','ET'],
  ['ADL','Australia','Adelaide','AU'],
  ['AMD','India','Ahmedabad','IN']
];
var templates = [
  ['{d-airport-code} | {d} | D','{d} air fare'],
  ['{d-airport-code} | {d} | D','{d} airfare'],
  ['{d-airport-code} | {d} | D','{d} airline ticket to'],
  ['{d-airport-code} | {d} | D','{d} flight']
];

/*
 * Build the map of <parameter,[values]> as an object
 * 
 * Example:
 *   {
 *     '{d-airport-code}' : ['ADD','ADL','AMD'],
 *     '{d-country}' : ['Ethiopia','Australia','India']
 *   }
 */
var combos = {};
for(var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
  combos[parameters[i]] = [];
  for(var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    combos[parameters[i]].push(values[j][i]);
  }
}

/*
 * Build the template representation: each template string is divided
 * in segments and placeholders.
 *
 * Note:
 *  an empty string is represented as <[""],[]>
 *  the string "{o}" is represented as <["",""],[{o}]>
 *
 * In summary:
 *  - there is always at least a segment
 *  - the number of segments is always the number of placeholders + 1
 */
var template_set = [];
for(var i = 0; i < templates.length; i++) {
  var template_set_row = [];
  for(var j = 0; j < templates[i].length; j++) {
    var segments = templates[i][j].split(/{[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}/);
    var placeholders = templates[i][j].match(/{[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}/g);
    template_set_row.push({
      'segments': segments,
      'placeholders': placeholders
    });

    /*
    var template = [];
    template.push(segments[0]);
    for (var k = 1; k < segments.length; k++) {
      template.push(combos[placeholders[k-1]]);
      template.push(segments[k]);
    }
    template_set_row.push(template);
    */
  }
  template_set.push(template_set_row);
}

var result_set = [];
// For every combination of values build the string
for(var v = 0; v < values.length; v++) {
  // For every template "row"
  for(var i = 0; i < template_set.length; i++) {
    var result_set_row = [];
    // For every single template string
    for(var j = 0; j < template_set[i].length; j++) {
      // There is always at least one placeholder
      var result = template_set[i][j].segments[0];

      // The number of segments is always the number of placeholders + 1
      // For every placeholder found
      for(var k = 0; k < template_set[i][j].placeholders.length; k++){
        result += combos[template_set[i][j].placeholders[k]][v];
        result += template_set[i][j].segments[k+1];
      }
      result_set_row.push(result);
    }
    result_set.push(result_set_row);
  }
}
```